# RUN yum install inside Dockerfile throwing error in Mac

Tags: macos, docker, dockerfile, yum, dockerfile-maven-plugin

Step 20/29 : RUN yum install -y docker-engine-18.09.8.ol-1.0.4.el7
 ---> Running in 9aa3b53a6171
Loaded plugins: ovl
https://artifactory.xxx.com/io-ol7-addons-yum-local/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] curl#60 - "Peer's Certificate issuer is not recognized."
Trying other mirror.

One of the configured repositories failed (io-ol7-addons-yum-local),
 and yum doesn't have enough cached data to continue. At this point the only
 safe thing yum can do is fail. There are a few ways to work "fix" this:

```
 1. Contact the upstream for the repository and get them to fix the problem.

 2. Reconfigure the baseurl/etc. for the repository, to point to a working
    upstream. This is most often useful if you are using a newer
    distribution release than is supported by the repository (and the
    packages for the previous distribution release still work).

 3. Run the command with the repository temporarily disabled
        yum --disablerepo=io-ol7-addons-yum-local ...

 4. Disable the repository permanently, so yum won't use it by default. Yum
    will then just ignore the repository until you permanently enable it
    again or use --enablerepo for temporary usage:

        yum-config-manager --disable io-ol7-addons-yum-local
    or
        subscription-manager repos --disable=io-ol7-addons-yum-local

 5. Configure the failing repository to be skipped, if it is unavailable.
    Note that yum will try to contact the repo. when it runs most commands,
    so will have to try and fail each time (and thus. yum will be be much
    slower). If it is a very temporary problem though, this is often a nice
    compromise:

        yum-config-manager --save --setopt=io-ol7-addons-yum-local.skip_if_unavailable=true
```

failure: repodata/repomd.xml from io-ol7-addons-yum-local: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
https://artifactory.xxx.com/io-ol7-addons-yum-local/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] curl#60 - "Peer's Certificate issuer is not recognized."

The command '/bin/sh -c yum install -y docker-engine-18.09.8.ol-1.0.4.el7' returned a non-zero code: 1

People working in linux sometimes faced the problem, and solved it by downloading the repo config and keeping it in path /etc/yum.repos.d/. But how to solve this in Mac where YUM is not used?

P.S. There is a proxy server and I have added the proxy settings properly in docker prefernces proxy setup.

Comment: were you able to resolve this ?